# Proving a bound on $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, supposing another bound holds

Tags: inequality

Let  $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be such that $$f(x)\leq e^{C \cdot t^2\cdot s^2-t\cdot x\cdot s},\quad \quad(1)$$for all $t\in[0,1]$ and for some positive $s,C$. I have to prove the bound $$f(x)\leq c_1\max(e^{c_2\cdot x^2},e^{-c_2\cdot s \cdot x})\quad\quad (2)$$for  some positive constants $c_i$ *independent of $s$*.

*What I did: I have to somehow make use of that fact that I can minimize the RHS of $(1)$ in $t$, since it holds for all $t$. The problem is the constraint on $t$ lying in $[0,1]$: If $h(t):=e^{C \cdot t^2\cdot s^2-t\cdot x\cdot s}$, then the minimum is at $t=\frac{x}{2Cs}$, at which $h$ has the value $$e^{\frac{x^2}{4C}},$$so if I set $c_2:=\frac{1}{4C}$ I can obtain the first term inside the $\max$, so it fulfills bound $(2)$.*

Question: This minimum lies in $[0,1]$ iff $x\leq2Cs$, so what do I have to do in the case $x\geq2Cs$ to prove  $(\star)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there is a typo in your question and that what you actually wanted to prove is that there are positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$f(x) \leq c_1 \text{max} (e^{-c_2x^2}, e^{-c_2 sx}).$$ In any case, if I prove this, I will also have proved the inequality (2) as written in your post since $e^{-c_2x^2} \leq e^{c_2 x^2}$.

Note that I can start by replacing $C$ in inequality (1) with $\text{max}(C,1)$ (since if inequality (1) holds for some $C < 1$, it certainly holds for $C = 1$ as well). I will therefore assume that $C \geq 1$.

Your argument for the case when $x \leq 2Cs$ works, but with one minor correction - actually the minimum of $h$ is $\exp(-\frac{x^2}{4c})$.

For $x > 2Cs$, the best bound we can get on $f(x)$ from (1) is the minimum value $Ct^2s^2 - txs$ attains for $t \in [0,1]$, which actually occurs at $t=1$ since the turning point of the polynomial is $\frac{x}{2Cs} > 1$. It follows that the best bound attainable from $(1)$ is $$f(x) \leq \begin{cases} e^{\frac{-x^2}{4C}} & \text{if } x \leq 2Cs \\ e^{Cs^2}e^{-xs} & x > 2Cs \end{cases}.$$

It follows that if $$e^{Cs^2}e^{-xs} \leq e^{-\frac{xs}{4C}}\quad\quad(3)$$ for $x > 2Cs$, then for all $x > 0$,
$$f(x) \leq \text{max}(e^{-\frac{x^2}{4C} }, e^{-\frac{xs}{4C}}),$$ i.e. I can take $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = \frac{1}{4C}$.

To show inequality (3), note that by taking logs, (3) holds iff $$Cs^2 - xs \leq -\frac{xs}{4C},$$ which, on rearranging is equivalent to,
$$xs(1-\frac{1}{4C}) \geq Cs^2.$$

This certainly holds for $x > 2Cs$ since (recalling that we have also replaced $C$ by $\text{max}(C,1) \geq 1$), for such values of $x$ we have 
$$xs(1-\frac{1}{4C}) \geq \frac{3}{4}xs > \frac{3}{4}2Cs \cdot s = \frac32Cs^2 > Cs^2.$$